# Get rid of invalid unicode character in string variable

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, string-parsing

I've put in a python3 requests get command (not sure if that's good phrasing), converted it to json, and have parsed it to receive the name:

```
'Harrison Elementary School \U0001f3eb'
```

I looked it up and the unicode character stands for a school, [Unicode School Character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3eb/index.htm). But when I print it, I get:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f3eb' in position 27: character maps to <undefined>
```

I really don't care about having that unicode character. It's not important for my purposes.

**How can I strip that unicode character and any other *invalid* characters from this or any string I come across?**

Comment: How and where are you printing it?  OS and terminal/IDE used matters.

Comment: Report Python version as well...for example, Python 3.6+ on Windows will print all Unicode characters in a terminal window without raising an exception, but if the font doesn't support the character, a replacement character is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to determine why the characters are invalid.  It appears that the error message was generated when you tried to print the string, meaning that the Unicode character could not be encoded using the default output encoding.  For `print` this should be `sys.stdout.encoding`.

You can encode the string yourself and ignore characters that are invalid, but that leaves you with a byte string.  It is necessary to `decode` those bytes back into a Unicode string.

```
def sanitize(s, encoding, errors='ignore'):
    return s.encode(encoding, errors=errors).decode(encoding)

>>> import sys
>>> print(sanitize('Harrison Elementary School \U0001f3eb', sys.stdout.encoding))
Harrison Elementary School
```

Answer (score 2):

The character is not really invalid, just `undefined`, so when you are encoding you can often tell the encoder how to handle errors:

```py
import codecs 

school_name = "Harrison Elementary School \U0001f3eb"
encoded_name = codecs.charmap_encode(school_name, 'ignore')
print(encoded_name)
```

With result `(b'Harrison Elementary School ', 28)`